# should I move this answer-in-question to an answer?

Tags: support

should I move this answer-in-question to an answer?

[Are there any disadvantages to always using nvarchar(MAX)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148398/are-there-any-disadvantages-to-always-using-nvarcharmax)

I have the edit privs, should I use them?

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions. In this case here, I'm wondering though if the "answer" is actually a summary of the answers below. If it *is*, then there is nothing to salvage, and it should just be removed. Otherwise, the answer-in-question should be removed from the question and posted as an answer.

Comment: Is it okay to post what he wrote as an answer under my own account? I could mark it as wiki

Comment: Some people have done what you suggest. As I see it, it is okay, and I know others have considered it okay when discussed on Meta. It is possible that you'll run into the odd user who thinks what you do amounts to "stealing". There's no much we can do about that.

Comment: done. cheers for the advice

Comment: @Jongware That OP sure showed you! When a question is relatively fresh, and it got the answer through an edit, I typically rollback and comment on the question. Most of the time the OP will post their answer. There are probably some cases where they don't and I forget to go back. I don't usually run into old questions that need editing for this reason (which is actually the case of the OP here: old question) so I'd probably just post myself, and mark as CW, rather than hope the OP will do it (which of course will automatically mean the OP will check out what is going on and be annoyed).